# Nexus S ICS update problem restarting by itself

Tags: updates, samsung-nexus-s, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a Nexus S (european edition, no super amoled screen), I upgraded to ICS in December but I think it has problem because it restarts itself very often and I don't know what have caused this behavior.

Anyone have similar problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes many people experienced problems. Have a look at: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=1c21a7e3690388b0&hl=en

where a Google employee is asking for information on the problems people are having and asking them to submit bug reports. Here's the generic bug report link for Nexus S with ICS:
http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/request.py?&contact_type=android_bugreport